# Objective-C - Serialize/De-serialize multiple arrays to/from a local file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I've read some SO posts here and there on how to write arrays to file but I'm having issues trying to figure out how to write (serialize) multiple arrays to a single file then read back later.  Based on what I've read so far I think the easiest way might be to use

`[array writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];`

but what's the best way to handle writing multiple arrays to a file?  My understanding is that each time you use the above method that it will re-write the entire file.

I have 8 arrays I need to serialize, and I would like to use newline (`\n`) to separate each array onto a new line in the file.  Can anyone provide guidance/psuedo code/Objective-c code for accomplishing this?

Comment: put all arrays into another array

Comment: I had thought of that, but then I need to insert special de-lineation characters to know when one array ends and the next starts, and add extra logic when reading them from file.  Is that really the best way?

Comment: No I mean make 2D array. `@[array1, array2]`

Comment: Ok yeah that seems to be working, sorry I'm a n00b to Objective-c.  If you want to create an answer out of that I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: You are making a mistake if you talk about writing arrays to a particular "line" of a file using methods like writeToFile. The output of writeToFile is a property list. It will almost certainly be a property list in XML format, where each array takes multiple lines, but whitespace is for display purposes, not as delimiters.

Comment: Yeah thanks I noticed that once I implemented that it does indeed save as xml in the plist, works great for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all your arrays in to another array and save that array.

```
NSArray *arrayToSave = @[array1, array2, array3];
[arrayToSave writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all the arrays into an NSDictionary, write the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the post, I'm sure this will work but want to stick to using arrays if possible.  I'll upvote your answer...

Comment: @Ergin Then put all the arrays into another array and write that?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing now, Bryan mentioned the same thing.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Methods like NSArray's writeToFile:atomically: method create property lists, which are specific kind of file unique to Cocoa/Cocoa touch. On recent platforms those methods create XML property lists.

You won't get an array per line with newline characters between them with property lists. The file will have XML tags in it, and newlines added for visual clarity. The newlines are not meaningful in the data format however.

If you want a particular byte format for your data, you'll need to write your own methods for serializing your arrays.

What makes you think you need newlines between the arrays?